# Select the record with minimum count

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, min

I have a setup like below:

Table - `Tasks`

```
| ResourceID |   Name   | T_SEQ | 
|    1       |  Res1    |   90  |
|    1       |  Res1    |   91  |
|    2       |  Res2    |   92  |
```

I am running the following:

```
select ResourceID, COUNT(ResourceID) 
from Tasks 
group by ResourceID
```

This shows me that Res1 has a count of 2 and Res2 has a count of 1.

Now I want to get the minimum, so in this case I need to get the ResourceID of 2 because it only has 1 job, but I'm not sure how to go about it?

Thanks for anyone who can help.

Comment: Add a few more rows of sample data, and also add the new expected result.

Comment: What happens if you have two with the same count?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method is `order by` and `top`:

```
select top 1 ResourceID, COUNT(ResourceID) 
from Tasks 
group by ResourceID
order by COUNT(ResourceID);
```

Comment: One doubt : If more than 1 ResourceId have same minimum count, then this query will result only one.

Comment: Perfect, no problem if ResourceId have the same min count, I just need it to pick the first / any.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this using CTEs. This will give you all rows which have the minimum count:

```
; WITH occurrences AS
(
    select ResourceID, COUNT(ResourceID) AS Counts
    from Tasks 
    group by ResourceID
)
, min_occurrences AS
(
    SELECT MIN(Counts) AS min_counts FROM occurrences
)
SELECT ResourceID FROM occurrences a
INNER JOIN min_occurrences b ON a.Counts = b.min_counts
```